# Why can't it locate the directory?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Was cooding a command handler in discord.js but ran into some trouble along the way, from my limited knowledge in javascript and discord.js the code should at least be able to find the directory.

[image]

Said code that's causing the headache:

```
const cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync('../cmds/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of cmdFiles) {
    console.log("hej");
    console.log(file);
    const cmd = require(`../cmds/${file}`);

    client.cmds.set(cmd.name, cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path passed to `fs.readdirSync()` is interpreted as relative to the *current working directory*, not to the JS file, so you probably should replace `../cmds/` by `./cmds/` or simply `cmds/`.

You can change the working directory by running the `cd` command before running Node.js.